# Random() returns zero but there is no zero value

Tags: java, arrays, random, zero

I have prepared a code to get a random number from an array of integers (1 - 10) to build a multiplication table.

```
    int[] anArrayOne = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    int[] anArrayTwo = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    int answer;
    int firstNumber = new Random().nextInt(anArrayOne.length);
    int secondNumber = new Random().nextInt(anArrayTwo.length);
System.out.println("What is" + firstNumber + " times "
+ secondNumber + "? ");
```

The code sometimes returns "0". Why is it the case if there is no 0 value assigned in neither of the arrays?

Comment: You are not using **content** of either of your arrays.

Comment: From [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt--):"Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value **between 0 (inclusive)** and the specified value (exclusive), drawn from this random number generator's sequence." (emphasis added)

Comment: BTW, don't initialize two different `Random`s; just use the same instance, and call `nextInt()` repeatedly on it. Conversely, you can just call `Math.random()` over and over again without instantiating anything.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be much reason to have the arrays. Just use `Random rnd = new Random(); int firstNumber = rnd.nextInt(10) + 1; int secondNumber = rnd.nextInt(10) + 1;`

Comment: I'll reduce it to just one array, but am I correct in thinking that if I wanted to avoid 0 value I should apply a loop to check for 0 returned and force the method to pick another value !=0?

Comment: Simpler: just add 1 to the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)

NextInt returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive),

So in other words, `nextInt` in your case  will return a value from 0 to 9 inclusive.

If you want to use the random number as an index into an array you could do something like @haba713 's answer above/below

Answer (score 1):

`new Random().nextInt(anArrayOne.length)` returns a random integer between 0 and `length` but you should use it as an index to select the actual value from an array like this:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int firstNumber = anArrayOne[rnd.nextInt(anArrayOne.length)];
int secondNumber = anArrayTwo[rnd.nextInt(anArrayTwo.length)];
```

Comment: You should actually explain what the issue was and what you did to fix it. Just dumping code doesn't help much.